# Google App Script OCR PDF to text Page Number Limitation

Tags: pdf, google-sheets, ocr

I am very new to Google Script. I have some pdf files in a folder on Google Drive and I am trying to convert pdf to google doc and extract specific text. PDF has more than 200 pages but even the google.doc file is limited to 80 pages. Is there a limit on number of pages you can run OCR on? Or I am missing something....

My code below:

//#####GLOBALS#####

```
const FOLDER_ID = "1rlAL4WrnxQ6pEY2uOmzWA_csUIDdBjVK"; //Folder ID of all PDFs
const SS = "1XS_YUUdu9FK_bBumK3lFu9fU_M9w7NGydZqOzu9vTyE";//The spreadsheet ID
```

SHEET = "Extracted";//The sheet tab name

/*########################################################

- Main run file: extracts student IDs from PDFs and their
- section from the PDF name from multiple documents.
- 
- Displays a list of students and sections in a Google Sheet.
- 

*/

```
function extractInfo(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  //Get all PDF files:
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
  //const files = folder.getFiles();
  const files = folder.getFilesByType("application/pdf");
  
  let allInfo = []
  //Iterate through each folderr
  while(files.hasNext()){
    Logger.log('first call');
    let file = files.next();
    let fileID = file.getId();
   
    const doc = getTextFromPDF(fileID);
    const invDate = extractInvDate(doc.text);
    
        
    allInfo = allInfo.concat(invDate);

Logger.log("Length of allInfo array: ")
Logger.log(allInfo.length);
    
  }
    importToSpreadsheet(allInfo);       //this is 80, even though pdf 
                                //has more than 200 pages with
                         //required text (invoice date) on each page
};


/*########################################################
 * Extracts the text from a PDF and stores it in memory.
 * Also extracts the file name.
 *
 * param {string} : fileID : file ID of the PDF that the text will be extracted from.
 *
 * returns {array} : Contains the file name  and PDF text.
 *
 */
function getTextFromPDF(fileID) {
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob()
  var resource = {
    title: blob.getName(),
    mimeType: blob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true, 
    ocrLanguage: "en"
  };
  // Convert the pdf to a Google Doc with ocr.
  var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, options);

  // Get the texts from the newly created text.
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  var title = doc.getName();
  
  // Deleted the document once the text has been stored.
  Drive.Files.remove(doc.getId());
  
  return {
    name:title,
    text:text
  };
}


function extractInvDate(text){
  const regexp = /Invoice Date:/g;//commented out \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/gi;
  try{
    let array = [...text.match (regexp)];
    return array;
  }catch(e){
    
  }
};


function importToSpreadsheet(data){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS).getSheetByName(SHEET);
  
  const range = sheet.getRange(3,1,data.length,1);
  
  var j = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
    Logger.log(j);
  range.getCell(j+1,1).setValue(data[j]);
  }
  //range.sort([2,1]);
}
```

Comment: Hi did you compare your pdf file and the converted docs for missing content? I don't have a sample pdf with 200 pages but I tried it on a 30 pages file and it was converted to docs with 26 pages removing some formats and spaces. Could you share a sample pdf file so I could try on my end as well if possible? please take note to remove sensitive information in your pdf file if you decided to share a sample file

Comment: Hi, @RonM . Thank you for willing to help. I compared the converted docs with my pdf. It clearly misses content after page 80. You can find a link below to sample file on my Google Drive. It contains 100 pages (page number inserted below each page). I run my code on this sample file after commenting out the line  Drive.Files.remove(doc.getId()); and the docs file has exactly 80 out of 100 pages. Apparently, there's limit of 80 pages to something involved in this code but I'm helplessly unable to figure out. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry can you share a link to your sample file?

Comment: Sorry, just forgot it :) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-RwjGaZbKtzheOLlFkjXpnID0jD4i1sO/view?usp=sharing           Also, I've just found out that OCR scans only first 80 pages of pdf. The link to this information is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-RwjGaZbKtzheOLlFkjXpnID0jD4i1sO/view?usp=sharing (Read the Blue Star Note )

Comment: Please let me know if you find a work around. Thanks, again.

Comment: Thank you for that information, I'm sorry to say but the last option I have in mind is for you to split your pdf file into multiple pages so that OCR could be supported. However, you cannot do that using apps script

Answer (score 0):

The problem or limitation is with the Drive.Files.insert function

When the blob is extracted, fetch the string but it has mime details also...one may need to process it. Sample code is below. modify as per ur need

```
var blob =  DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob()
var txt = blob.getDataAsString()
```